# Meteor user adding form doesn't do anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, user-accounts

So I made my own user adding form so that only logged in users can add new ones. Here's my Jade:

```
template(name="userAdd")
.sixteen.wide.column
  h1 Add new user
  form#userAddForm.ui.form
    .field.required
      label(for="username") Username:
      input(type="text" name="username")#username
    .field.required
      label(for="email") Email:
      input(type="email" name="email")#email
    .field.required
      label(for="password") Password:
      input(type="password" name="password")#password
    .field.required
      label(for="realname") Real Name:
      input(type="text" name="realname")#realname
    .field.required
      label(for="bio") Bio:
      textarea(rows="3" name="bio")#bio
    button(type="submit")#usersubmit.ui.button.primary Submit
```

And the Javascript:

```
Template.userAdd.events({
  'click #usersubmit': function (evt) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: $('input #username').val(),
      email: $('input #email').val(),
      password: $('input #password').val(),
      profile: {
        realname: $('input #realname').val(),
        bio: $('input #bio').val()
      }
    })

    Router.go('/')
  }
})
```

For some reason, this only redirects me back to the same page and doesn't do anything, not even something shows in the dev console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is actually submitting the form. You need to stop the form from submitting. Use the following code.

```
Template.userAdd.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        Accounts.createUser({
            username: event.target.username.value,
            email: event.target.email.value,
            password: event.target.password.value,
            profile: {
                realname: event.target.realname.value,
                bio: event.target.bio.value
            }
        });

        Router.go('/');
    }
});
```

Notice that I use event.target.*inputName*.value which is the best practice way of dealing with form data in Meteor.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Redirects to / but doesn't insert anything. Should I add some security rules?

Comment: Why don't you try to debug this code? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser Place a callback inside the function with some console.logs and look at the error or the succesful creation of a user. createUser creates a user client side and and then logs in as that user. Accounts already has all kinds of security already.

Comment: Okay, I had signups disabled for some reason.